# Group the data by semesters in Power BI

Tags: python, html, css, powerbi, dax

I need your help.

I downloaded HTML & CSS viewer in Power BI Desktop and I try to write a DAX code in it.
I can write a code for semesters and for courses separately but I could not put the courses according to their semesters to show what courses a student have passed in concrete semester.

I could reach only this visual at this moment using these formulas below:

Course Name
    "& CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT('Courses'[Semester ID ]), "  "& 'Courses'[Semester ID ],,'Courses'[Semester ID ],ASC)&"
    "&CONCATENATEX(FILTER('Courses','Courses'[Semester ID ]='Courses'[Semester ID ]),"   "& 'Courses'[Course Name ] &" ","",'Courses'[Semester ID ],ASC) &"

[image]

I want to achieve this result instead of visual I created above:
[image]

If it is not enough information here, I can send you a Power BI example file with gmail.

Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: Please add sample data and your expected output from them. It will be easier to understand then.